# it was not, in reality, so distant

Tags: pronouns

What does the boldfaced pronoun it refer to in the following extract from *Frankenstein*?

> This appearance excited our unqualified wonder. We were, as we believed, many hundred miles from any land; but this apparition seemed to denote that **it** was not, in reality, so distant as we had supposed. Shut in, however, by ice, it was impossible to follow his track, which we had observed with the greatest attention.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: @Later The issue is whether that reference is grammatically possible in English.

Comment: Why should it not be possible? "Reference" is the relationship between a grammatical unit that refers to another grammatical unit, and so a pronoun may point back to other items in a text.

Comment: There are conditions on the reference between an antecedent and a pronoun. Consider "A: Do you have any water? B: Yes, I have it." Here, "it" fails to refer to "any water."

Comment: Why can "it" not refer to "any water"?

Comment: "Any water" refers to an indefinite amount, whereas "it" refers to something definite.

Comment: No, it is not necessary that "it" must refer to a definite amount of something; "it" can refer to any non-plural noun phrase.

Comment: You could ask any native speaker about that two-sentence dialogue. A bound variable interpretation is possible only under certain conditions.